# Style SwipeRefreshLayout in r21 of support library

Tags: android, android-support-library, swiperefreshlayout

I couldn't find any documentation on how to style the new `refreshIcon` in the `swipeRefreshLayout` ?

```
this.swipeRefreshLayout.setProgressBackgroundColor(R.color.feed_refresh_1);
```

this just changes the `<background color>` of the refresh icon background, is there a way to change the color of the arrow itself?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the latest r21, you can change the spinning arrow tint passing just one color to one of these methods:

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(Color.RED);
```

or:

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_red_dark);
```

Tested and working on Android 5.0.2, should also work with every other version since v4.
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Use `this.swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(..);`
or `this.swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(..);`.

See [Android API reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#setColorSchemeResources(int...)).

Answer (score 0):

not sure which icon you talk about, that layout is just a line at the top as far as I know. Instead of the official SwipeRefreshLayout I use https://github.com/baoyongzhang/android-PullRefreshLayout which have 4 styles, you probably mean the material design.

Comment: The latest update changed the line to be the new material design reload icon -> a rounded floatingactionbutton-like activity indicator ;)

Comment: aha, its probably API dependent then, because if I import and use android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout now with api 18, I have that line.

Comment: I think it depends on the version of the support lib, in r 21 the icon appears